Images overflow .container-wrapper despite overflow: hidden; not working
I'm working on a custom section for a website where I have a .container-wrapper element containing text and multiple images. The container is supposed to have overflow: hidden; to prevent overflow issues. However, the images inside .images-wrapper are still overflowing the container's bounds.
Here's a simplified version of my HTML and CSS structure:

<section class="custom-section">
  <div class="container-wrapper">
    <!-- Text and other content -->
    
    <div class="images-wrapper">
      <img src="image1.jpg" alt="Image 1">
      <img src="image2.jpg" alt="Image 2">
      <img src="image3.jpg" alt="Image 3">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>




.custom-section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; /* Adjust as needed */
  height: 650px; /* Adjust as needed */
}

.custom-section .container-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; /* Adjust as needed */
  height: 100%; /* Adjust as needed */
  overflow: hidden; /* Should hide overflow */
}

.custom-section .images-wrapper {
  width: 100%; /* Adjust as needed */
  height: 100%; /* Adjust as needed */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; /* Adjust as needed */
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
}

.custom-section .images-wrapper img {
  width: 300px; /* Adjust as needed */
  height: 430px; /* Adjust as needed */
}



Despite setting overflow: hidden; on .container-wrapper, the last image in .images-wrapper still overflows visibly. I've checked the widths and positioning, and everything seems correct.
What could be causing this issue? How can I ensure that overflow: hidden; effectively hides the overflowing images within .container-wrapper?
This is how it looks now:
This is how it looks now

Why have you got position absolute?

When I make it to relative or remove it, it completely changes the design and structure.

Since the .container-wrapper has no specific width the overflow: hidden won't have any effect. Just add a max-width, and it will be just fine, like so:


.custom-section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 650px; 
}

.custom-section .container-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 1100px; /*this is the important new code. Adjust as desired*/
}

.custom-section .images-wrapper {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; 
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
}

.custom-section .images-wrapper img {
  width: 300px; 
  height: 430px; 
}
<section class="custom-section">
  <div class="container-wrapper">
    <!-- Text and other content -->

    <div class="images-wrapper">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Image 1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Image 2">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Image 3">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Image 4"><!-- for illustration only-->
    </div>
  </div>
</section>




Thank you so much!
Btw, is there any other way, for example, something that will preserve the 'div' container?

You're very welcome! If you specify a 100% width for a div, its child won't be cut down by the width of the parent div. So there's no other alternative - I'm afraid - in terms of overflow: hidden. In other words: if the parent is larger than the child, the child won't be "cut".

Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help! You are amazing! :)

I'm glad you are satisfied. Thank you :)
